# How can I remove unattached MySQL users?

Tags: mysql

I've too many MySQL databases and each database has separate user attached with it. I was working on server and removed few databases but now there are mysql users available who are not attached with any database? How can I find them and delete these users... I've root access of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

There are way too many variables for this. But a ***good*** start in mysql database and search for users in **`user`** table without being present in the **`db`** table and no GLOBAL `Select_priv`

```
use mysql;
select * from user
   where User NOT IN (select User from db)
   AND Select_priv = 'N'\G
```

In my case, this yielded the user I use for `Repl_slave_priv` (used for replication).

You can AND a bunch of privileges, like `Super_priv`